# IF statement returns incorrect value when compared to INDEX value

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to check a value from another Sheet but getting some incorrect results.

The function below is returning true.

```
=IF($'Score Data'.$G8<INDEX(lookupParData,MATCH($'Score Data'.$B8,cParNames,0),1))
```

The 2 functions below is returning 3. (the expected result)

```
=INDEX(lookupParData,MATCH($'Score Data'.$B8,cParNames,0),1)
=INDEX(lookupParData,2,1)
```

The function below is returning 6. (expected result)

```
=$'Score Data'.$G8
```

If I replace the $'Score Data'.$G8 with a 6 it still returns true.
If I replace the INDEX(lookupParData,MATCH($'Score Data'.$B8,cParNames,0),1) with a 3 in the IF function above it returns false.

I believe it is something to do with the INDEX function but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the data in `lookupParData`, but I'm not sure - you didn't say which values are in the first column of that range, numbers or text. Please press CTRL+F8 and see if the values in this range are black or blue? Also check the color of 'Score Data'.$G8. The error may be in the comparison operator `<` - comparing numbers and text rarely gives the expected result.

Comment: Would you mind to add a [mre], please?